Read Excel Files via SFTP Spark
I have an SFTP Server with Excel Files and I want to read them with my Spark Application. I found Spark-sftp to do the job, but I see only csv files are supported.
How can I use it to read xlsx file? Or, alternatively, is there a better way to read xlsx files in Spark from an sftp server?
